# How To Use DISTINCT With a Join?

Tags: mysql

This is practice with the MySQL Employees DB. The diagram for it is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/sakila-structure.html).

I want to know the top 10 `salaries.salary`, by `employees.gender`.

I have tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT employees.emp_no, employees.first_name, employees.last_name, employees.gender, salaries.salary 
FROM employees 
JOIN salaries ON employees.emp_no = salaries.emp_no 
ORDER BY salaries.salary DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

```sh
+--------+------------+-----------+--------+--------+
| emp_no | first_name | last_name | gender | salary |
+--------+------------+-----------+--------+--------+
|  43624 | Tokuyasu   | Pesch     | M      | 158220 |
|  43624 | Tokuyasu   | Pesch     | M      | 157821 |
| 254466 | Honesty    | Mukaidono | M      | 156286 |
|  47978 | Xiahua     | Whitcomb  | M      | 155709 |
| 253939 | Sanjai     | Luders    | M      | 155513 |
| 109334 | Tsutomu    | Alameldin | M      | 155377 |
| 109334 | Tsutomu    | Alameldin | M      | 155190 |
| 109334 | Tsutomu    | Alameldin | M      | 154888 |
| 109334 | Tsutomu    | Alameldin | M      | 154885 |
|  80823 | Willard    | Baca      | M      | 154459 |
+--------+------------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

It's almost right, but what happened with my `DISTINCT`? I don't want so see the same `emp_no` in the table.

Comment: `DISTINCT` applies to the entire `SELECT` list. Since the salaries are different, the rows aren't duplicates.

Comment: Suggestions on how to get this w/o duplicate `emp_no`?

Comment: You should join with a subquery that just gets the most recent salary for each employy. You're getting multiple rows because you're showing their entire salary history.

Comment: What is the rule for which of the "duplicate" employee records to retain?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?noredirect=1&lq=1 for how to get the row the maximum date.

Comment: Just want to get the highest salary for each employee. So, see the top 10 without involving salary history - only top 10 with highest salary for each `emp_no`.

Comment: Then use `MAX(salary)` and `GROUP BY emp_no`. `GROUP BY` will make it distinct.

Comment:  `SELECT DISTINCT employees.first_name, employees.last_name, employees.gender, MAX(salaries.salary) FROM employees JOIN salaries ON employees.emp_no = salaries.emp_no GROUP BY employees.emp_no ORDER BY salaries.salary DESC LIMIT 10;` is what I have now. Getting error related to: `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT employees.emp_no, employees.first_name, employees.last_name, employees.gender, 
       MAX(salaries.salary) AS salary 
FROM employees 
JOIN salaries ON employees.emp_no = salaries.emp_no 
GROUP BY employees.emp_no 
ORDER BY salary DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

```sh
+--------+------------+-----------+--------+--------+
| emp_no | first_name | last_name | gender | salary |
+--------+------------+-----------+--------+--------+
|  43624 | Tokuyasu   | Pesch     | M      | 158220 |
| 254466 | Honesty    | Mukaidono | M      | 156286 |
|  47978 | Xiahua     | Whitcomb  | M      | 155709 |
| 253939 | Sanjai     | Luders    | M      | 155513 |
| 109334 | Tsutomu    | Alameldin | M      | 155377 |
|  80823 | Willard    | Baca      | M      | 154459 |
| 493158 | Lidong     | Meriste   | M      | 154376 |
| 205000 | Charmane   | Griswold  | M      | 153715 |
| 266526 | Weijing    | Chenoweth | F      | 152710 |
| 237542 | Weicheng   | Hatcliff  | F      | 152687 |
+--------+------------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

works!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html) to collapse extra lines

```
SELECT employees.emp_no, employees.first_name,
  employees.last_name, employees.gender, 
  AVG(salaries.salary) as salary
FROM employees 
JOIN salaries ON employees.emp_no = salaries.emp_no
GROUP BY employees.emp_no 
ORDER BY salary DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

| emp_no | first_name | last_name | gender | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 43624 | Tokuyasu | Pesch | M | 158020.5000 |
| 254466 | Honesty | Mukaidono | M | 156286.0000 |
| 47978 | Xiahua | Whitcomb | M | 155709.0000 |
| 253939 | Sanjai | Luders | M | 155513.0000 |
| 109334 | Tsutomu | Alameldin | M | 155085.0000 |
| 80823 | Willard | Baca | M | 154459.0000 |

Comment: We can add `ROUND(AVG(salaries.salary, 2)` also. But, why are we doing `AVG`?  Ur taking average of the salaries that they have ever earned instead of highest. It's a different result **technically,** but gives the same results, pretty much. .

Comment: Thanks,  of course you are right, but I added a link to functions to decide what need)

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
SELECT e.*
     , s.salary 
  FROM employees e
  JOIN salaries s
    ON s.emp_no = e.emp_no 
  JOIN (SELECT emp_no,MAX(salary) salary FROM salaries GROUP BY emp_no) x
    ON x.emp_no = s.emp_no 
   AND x.salary = s.salary
 ORDER 
    BY s.salary DESC 
 LIMIT 10;
```